# SwiftUI view appeares lifted by the size of keyboard

Tags: swiftui

I have view but everything is lifted by the size of keyboard. View does not have any input fields, keyboard is not visible. Previous screen had few text inputs and it happens when edit single last textfield value and set new view as a root of app.

```
        ZStack {
            Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Top")
                Spacer()
                Text("Bottom")
                Divider().background(Color.white)
            }
        }
```

Example project: https://github.com/cheskapac/lifted-view
Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch app
2. Allow to use Face ID
3. Cancel biometry authentication
4. Tap on Login button
5. Edit `Code` text field
6. Tap on `Submit` button
7. Authenticate with Face ID
8. You will get lifted view

Comment: If this issue is dependent on the other view and doesn't occur with just the code you've provided, can you include that in a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx I've edited description, provided example project with steps to reproduce

Comment: I've found one workaround but I'm not happy with it: Resign keyboard and navigate after 500ms